# SendMessage to window created by AllocateHWND cause deadlock

Tags: multithreading, delphi, deadlock, sendmessage

In my Delphi project, I derive a thread class TMyThread, and follow the advice from forums to use AllocateHWnd to create a window handle. In TMyThread object, I call SendMessage to send message to the window handle.

When the messages sent are in small volume, then the application works well. However, when the messages are in large volume, the application will deadlock and lose responses. I think may be the message queue is full as in LogWndProc, there are only codes to process the message, but no codes to remove the messages from the queue, that may cause all the processed messages still exist in the queue and the queue becomes full. Is that correct?

The codes are attached below:

```
var
hLogWnd: HWND = 0;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
hLogWnd := AllocateHWnd(LogWndProc);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
if hLogWnd <> 0 then
DeallocateHWnd(hLogWnd);
end;

procedure TForm1.LogWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
S: PString;
begin
if Message.Msg = WM_UPDATEDATA then
begin
S := PString(msg.LParam);
try
List1.Items.Add(S^);
finally
Dispose(S);
end;
end else
Message.Result := DefWindowProc(hLogWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam,
Message.LParam);
end;

procedure TMyThread.SendLog(I: Integer);
var
Log: PString;
begin
New(Log);
Log^ := 'Log: current stag is ' + IntToStr(I);
SendMessage(hLogWnd, WM_UPDATEDATA, 0, LPARAM(Log));
Dispose(Log);
end;
```

Comment: By the way, it's time that you learnt how to accept answers. Please look back at your previous questions.

Answer (score 6):

You are disposing your allocated string twice.  At best, you will get an exception in your worker thread after `SendMessage()` has exited, terminating your thread if you do not catch that exception.  At worse, you might not get an exception, but you will trash memory, leaving your app in a bad state so all sorts of random things can happen.  You need to dispose the allocated string only once.

You are not responsible for removing sent messages from the queue because `SendMessage()` does not put the message into the queue.  However, it does require the receiving thread to pump its queue for new messages, even if there are no new messages in the queue, in order to dispatch sent messages that are crossing thread boundaries, like your message is.  If `SendMessage()` is blocking then your main thread is not pumping the queue correctly in code you have not shown, such as if you have other code that has blocked the main message loop from running.

As for the code you did show, I would suggest the following change:

```
procedure TForm1.LogWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_UPDATEDATA then
    List1.Items.Add(PString(Message.LParam)^)
  else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(hLogWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

procedure TMyThread.SendLog(I: Integer);
var
  Log: String;
begin
  Log := 'Log: current stag is ' + IntToStr(I);
  SendMessage(hLogWnd, WM_UPDATEDATA, 0, LPARAM(@Log));
end;
```

You do not need to dynamically allocate the string if you use `SendMessage()`, since it blocks the calling thread until the message is processed, ensuring the string remains valid. If you were using `PostMessage()` instead, then you would need to dynamically allocate (and fix your erroneous use of `Dispose()`):

```
procedure TForm1.LogWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  S: PString;
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_UPDATEDATA then
  begin
    S := PString(msg.LParam);
    try
      List1.Items.Add(S^);
    finally
      Dispose(S);
    end;
  end else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(hLogWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

procedure TMyThread.SendLog(I: Integer);
var
  Log: PString;
begin
  New(Log);
  Log^ := 'Log: current stag is ' + IntToStr(I);
  if not PostMessage(hLogWnd, WM_UPDATEDATA, 0, LPARAM(Log)) then
    Dispose(Log);
end;
```